# How to login to an application directly from command line, i.e by providing URL, username, password in the command line of a Pytest

Tags: python

Instead of hard coding the URL of the application under test in the code, I would like to pass it as an argument in the command line. Also, the username, password.

Currently I get below error

ERROR: file not found:

> pytest -v -s --html=.\Reports\report.html test_practise.py https://testurl

Below is my Login function:

```
class LoginPage():

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver
        self.url = 'https://test-url'


def go(self):
    self.driver.get(self.url)    


def enter_username(self,text):
    username_xpath = "//input[@id='emailOrUsername']"
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, username_xpath))).send_keys(text)


def enter_password(self,text):    
    password_xpath = "//input[@id='pass']"
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, password_xpath))).send_keys(text)


def click_login_button(self):    
    login_btn_xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Login')]"
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_btn_xpath).click()

def get_login_btn_text(self):
    login_btn_xpath = "//span[contains(text(),'Login')]"
    login_btn_text = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(login_btn_xpath).text
    return login_btn_text
```

Comment: use `import sys` and run your script code.py -u google.com then try `print(sys.argv)` to find where the google.com is there

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). Check the tutorial [by the link](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html).

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("echo")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.echo)
```

And here is a result:
    $ python3 prog.py --help
    usage: prog.py [-h] echo

```
positional arguments:
  echo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
$ python3 prog.py foo
foo
```

Comment: I tried adding argparse. However, at the end I still get the error ERROR: file not found:

Comment: File not found it is not related to request to parse arguments. It is a completely different problem related to either HTML report generation or finding file `test-practice.py`. Could you provide a full stack trace of your error?

Comment: (mydemo) C:\Users\g.siddalingappa\git\ctAssets\ct_assets_seleniumpythontestng>pytest -v -s --html=.\Reports\report.html test_practise.py https://ethanadmin:9fdd4289ade03078@a0c7f7f818d9711e99d7d0620471b1cb-427290137.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com/rocketchat/direct/bot ethanadmin 9fdd4289ade03078
===test session starts 
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.0.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.12.0 -- c:\users\g.siddalingappa\virtualenvs\mydemo\scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache

Comment: metadata: {'Python': '3.7.4', 'Platform': 'Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0', 'Packages': {'pytest': '5.0.1', 'py': '1.8.0', 'pluggy': '0.12.0'}, 'Plugins': {'html': '1.21.1', 'metadata': '1.8.0'}, 'JAVA_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_171'}
rootdir: C:\Users\g.siddalingappa\git\ctAssets\ct_assets_seleniumpythontestng
plugins: html-1.21.1, metadata-1.8.0
collected 0 items

Comment: generated html file: file://C:\Users\g.siddalingappa\git\ctAssets\ct_assets_seleniumpythontestng\Reports\report.html ---------------------------
====================================================================== no tests ran in 0.15 seconds =======================================================================
ERROR: file not found: https://ethanadmin:9fdd4289ade03078@a0c7f7f818d9711e99d7d0620471b1cb-427290137.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com/rocketchat/direct/bot

Comment: Could you try to run `python -m pytest <rest of the code>` (or `python3` if this is your alias for Python3)?

Comment: @gangakiran can you provide the error text? and how you typed the code?

Comment: test_practise.py

Comment: Now i get a different error: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'

Comment: import openpyxl
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from Pages.test_LoginPage import LoginPage
from Pages.ChatPage import ChatPage
import Utils.XLUtils
import pytest
import argparse


browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/g.siddalingappa/git/ctAssets/ct_assets_seleniumpythontestng/Driver/chromedriver.exe')
browser.maximize_window()
login = LoginPage(driver=browser)
chat = ChatPage(driver=browser)

Comment: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("url", help="URL of the application:chat bot URL")
parser.add_argument("username", help="name of the user")
parser.add_argument("password", help="password of the user")
        
args = parser.parse_args()
         
  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    login.go(args.url)

Comment: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import argparse


class LoginPage():
    
        def __init__(self, driver, args):
        self.driver = driver
        self.args = args.url
        
    def go(self, args):
        self.driver.get(args.url)